# Facebook events feed shows timezone as "UNK" instead of "UTC+02" as it should

Tags: facebook, apple, timezone

I have setup a Facebook Newsfeed up on our website. But on all Apple devices (i have tested), it shows the timezone as "UNK", but it should be - and is "UTC+02" on all other devices.

The code is as below, so it can't be that right?
The page it's happening on is: dr-louise.dk/eventkalender/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/da_DK/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0&appId=177456802812014&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="B3OPJqMi"></script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/drlouisedk/" data-tabs="events" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/drlouisedk/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/drlouisedk/">DRONNING LOUISE</a></blockquote></div>
```

How do i figure out what is wrong? I have tried 5 different apple devices, all with the same 09.00 UNK result, instead of (as it should be) 18.00 UTC+02.

Comment: And it works as expected on non Apple devices?

Comment: If the issue is specific to Apple devices, you may have to write to FB support on this. May be some client js that returns local timezone to FB servers is behaving incorrectly - Just a guess.

Comment: Yes it works as expected on non-Apple devices. Couldnt imagine ever getting response from FB on this, but will give it a try

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'm getting the same problem on a Linux device.

Answer (score 1):

This is also occurring on in Brave and Edge on Windows and Brave on Android where I am not logged into Facebook. If I am logged into Facebook, it displays as my timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I also see this behaviour as of 14 July 2021. It seems that "UNK" is San Francisco time (PST/PDT), so a workaround for users like me who don't have a Facebook account is to enter the date and time into a [timezone converter](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20210714T020000&p1=224) to see it in one's local time zone.